# What causes the pre-1.8 Minecraft far lands to generate?

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, procedural-generation

Before Minecraft Beta 1.8, when you reached about x:3000000 y:3000000, the terrain generator would freak out and begin generating broken scary land.
What went on in the MC code to provoke this? Why didn't it just completely stop generating? Why does the game still break at locations very far from spawn? What is the cause of this game breaking bug?

Comment: Notch wrote about this himself in [Terrain generation, Part 1](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/3746989361/terrain-generation-part-1). He wasn't actually aware of what caused it, and according to [the Minecraft Wiki page on the Far Lands](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Far_Lands) the fix was entirely by accident.

Comment: Is this more than just a trivia question? Or are you experiencing/trying to avoid something similar with your terrain generation code?

Comment: @JonathanHobbs, your comment is the answer, you could post it as an answer and get upvote for it.

Comment: @BobSort No it isn't. I was just saying Notch doesn't know, which isn't answering what happens. Someone else might've dug into the code and found out exactly what was happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the game still break at locations very far from spawn?

Everything has a limit, especially the numbers on a computer. Assuming he uses floating point numbers in most places, the precision at that point would be very low. My calculations say that it's about 0.25: http://ideone.com/xD7Tm

> the terrain generator would freak out and begin generating broken scary land

My guess is that position properties were added in the seed value, making it break a lot of calculations along the way.